# Multiplying a pandas column by a yearly coefficient in a fast way

Tags: python, performance, pandas, multiplication

I have a dataframe with datetime index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'test':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]},
    index=[
        '2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03',
        '2019-01-03', '2019-01-02', '2020-01-02'
    ]
 )
df.index=  pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

I have a yearly parameter:

```
yearly_parameter = [1, 2, 3]
```

I would like to multiply efficiently (in a vectorized way?) the column 'test' by it's corresponding yearly parameter contained in the list yearly_parameter (first value is for 2018, second for 2019 and third for 2020). How can I do that efficiently? Is a list a good way to store those yearly parameters to do the calculation?

I expect the following result in a column, say 'answer':

```
df['answer'] = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

print(df)

              test  answer
2018-01-01     1       1
2018-01-02     1       1
2018-01-03     1       1
2019-01-03     1       2
2019-01-02     1       2
2020-01-02     1       3
```

Thank you very much for your help,

Pierre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html)

Use `factorize` to establish an ordering of years that should correspond to elements in `yearly_parameter`.  Then we can efficiently multiply with array slicing.

This expects that the length of `yearly_parameter` be at least as long as the number of unique years in `df.index`

```
f, y = pd.factorize(df.index.year)

yearly_parameter = np.array([1, 2, 3])

df.assign(answer=df.test.values * yearly_parameter[f])

            test  answer
2018-01-01     1       1
2018-01-02     1       1
2018-01-03     1       1
2019-01-03     1       2
2019-01-02     1       2
2020-01-02     1       3
```

---

### [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)

Mind that this assumes that `yearly_parameter` aligns its first element with the first year that is observed.  If you intend for the first element to correspond to the minimum year observed then you should use `pd.factorize(df.index.year, sort=True)`.  Or better yet, if you are going to sort then use an equivalent calculation in Numpy

```
y, f = np.unique(df.index.year, return_inverse=True)

yearly_parameter = np.array([1, 2, 3])

df.assign(answer=df.test.values * yearly_parameter[f])

            test  answer
2018-01-01     1       1
2018-01-02     1       1
2018-01-03     1       1
2019-01-03     1       2
2019-01-02     1       2
2020-01-02     1       3
```